# Get values as types from an interface in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, interface, typescript-generics

i have an interface as follows

```
export interface GroupByCategoryAndTrigger {
  [key: string]: {
    label: string;
    name: string;
    triggers: {
      [key: string]: { name: string, label: string };
    }
  }
}
```

with value as follows:

```
export const CATEGORIES: GroupByCategoryAndTrigger = {
  reservation: {
    name: 'Reservation' as const,
    label: 'Reservation',
    triggers: {
      created: { name: 'created', label: 'Reservation created' },
      confirmation: {
        name: 'confirmation' as const,
        label: 'Reservation confirmed',
      },
      edited: {
        name: 'edited' as const,
        label: 'Reservation edited',
      },
      canceled: {
        name: 'canceled' as const,
        label: 'Reservation cancelled',
      },
      reminder1: {
        name: 'reminder_1' as const,
        label: 'Reminder 1',
      },
      reminder2: {
        name: 'reminder_2' as const,
        label: 'Reminder 2',
      },
      reminder3: {
        name: 'reminder_3' as const,
        label: 'Reminder 3',
      },

      payment: {
        name: 'payment' as const,
        label: 'Awaiting Payment',
      },
      feedbackRequest: {
        name: 'feedback_request' as const,
        label: 'Feedback request',
      },
    },
  },
  queue: {
    name: 'Offline Waitlist' as const,
    label: 'Queue',
    triggers: {
      waitlistConfirmation: {
        name: 'waitlist_confirmation' as const,
        label: 'Waitlist confirmation',
      },
      tableConfirmation: { name: 'table_confirmation' as const, label: 'Table confirmation' },
    },
  },
};
```

What i want is to get all values as a `union` type for Category names and Trigger names

what i am doing right now is as follows:

```
export type CategoriesValues = typeof CATEGORIES[keyof GroupByCategoryAndTrigger]['name']; //  "Reservation" | "Offline Waitlist"

export type TriggerValues =
  typeof CATEGORIES[keyof GroupByCategoryAndTrigger]['triggers'][string]['name']; //  "confirmation" | "canceled"
```

Looking for forward to get what the possible solution for this ?
P.S: i am newbie in typescript.

Comment: `const CATEGORIES: GroupByCategoryAndTrigger` makes `typeof CATEGORIES[keyof GroupByCategoryAndTrigger]` to equal to `GroupByCategoryAndTrigger[keyof GroupByCategoryAndTrigger]`

Comment: hi @Dimava, this would not result type wil values  `type  CategoriesValues = "Reservation" | "Offline Waitlist"`

Answer (score 0):

So the solution we figured was to rephrase the `GroupByCategoryAndTrigger` interface by explicitly giving `union` values as a type to `CategoryValues` and `TriggerValues` by assigning to the `name` of category and trigger inside `GroupByCategoryAndTrigger`

```
export type CategoryValues = 'Reservation' | 'Offline Waitlist';

export type TriggerValues =
  | 'created'
  | 'confirmation'
  | 'edited'
  | 'canceled'
  | 'reminder_1'
  | 'reminder_2'
  | 'reminder_3'
  | 'payment'
  | 'feedback_request'
  | 'waitlist_confirmation'
  | 'table_confirmation';

export interface GroupByCategoryAndTrigger {
  [key: string]: {
    label: string;
    name: CategoryValues;
    triggers: {
      [key: string]: { name: TriggerValues; label: string };
    };
  };
}
```